# How I can make that users from a Active Directory Folder can see a webform in my ASP.NEt Application?

Tags: c#, asp.net, authentication, active-directory, windows-authentication

I have built a ASP.NET Application that is for Guestconnection and this have a navigation with

- Add User
- Log
- Help

This Application will be run in our intranet (sharepoint) and I want that only user from a folder in active directory (for example guestadmin) see the navigation log.

Here is my master site:

```
...
<div class="cssmenu" id='cssmenu'>
                    <ul>
                       <li class='active'><a href='UserList.aspx'><span>Benutzer</span></a></li>    
                        <% if (true)
                          { %>    
                          <li><a href='log.aspx'><span>Aufzeichnung</span></a></li>               

                       <% } %>                 
                       <li ><a href='help.aspx'><span>Hilfe</span></a></li>
                    </ul>
                 </div>
...
```

If the authen.. user is in this ad folder than I want to get true else false.

Answer (score 0):

i guess.this can be done through using the directory services and you can search for the user in the active directory and then perform the needed operations.try using namespace active directory directory services

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [Role Provider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6b241xwt%28v=vs.100%29.aspx). There are a few implementations, including [WindowsTokenRoleProvider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.windowstokenroleprovider%28v=VS.80%29.aspx).

Here are the basic web.config/system.web settings:

```
<authentication mode="Windows" />

<authorization>
  <allow roles="BUILTIN\Administrators" />
    <deny users="*" />
  </authorization>

<roleManager defaultProvider="WindowsProvider" 
  enabled="true"
  cacheRolesInCookie="false">
  <providers>
    <add
      name="WindowsProvider"
      type="System.Web.Security.WindowsTokenRoleProvider" />
  </providers>
</roleManager>
```